# How does Cooper (the dad) end up in "Cooper Station"?

Tags: interstellar

How does Cooper end up in Cooper Station after he loses consciousness in the Tesseract?

Comment: You can actually see him floating around in space near planet(looks like venus) while some lights,presumably from a spaceship, are coming in his direction.

Comment: @gruntswilldie: “looks like venus” — I think it’s Saturn, the planet that Cooper Station orbits.

Answer (score 19):

It seemed quite clear from the film that "they" (whoever set up the tesseract, probably future humans) "dumped" him into space and the present-day humans found him.

As soon as he did what he had to in there, the robot commented that "they" were shutting down that place and soon afterwards Cooper was floating in space.

Comment: Also worth noting that "they" dumped him at a time where he would likely be found quickly by the approaching station (which happens to be many decades after his entry into the black hole.)

Answer (score 5):

This is one of a number of homages in Interstellar to *2001: A Space Odyssey*.

At the start of the fourth book, *3001: A Final Odyssey*, Frank Poole, who was killed by HAL, is found floating in space near Neptune and rescued.

"They" returned Cooper to his own spacetime in a manner such that he would be rescued.

Comment: I am glad you noted the 2001 homages! I kept seeing them throughout the film... from the "space is inaudible" representation, to Cooper awaking from his journey in an all white room. :)

Comment: not to mention ZImmer's heavy use of pipe organ in the score - evoking Strauss' *Also Sprach Zarathustra*